# Java Web Service get smtp email address format

Tags: lotus-domino

I have a java web service.  The underlying notes db has a form that has a field that is of type "names".  There is a view that is defined that contains a list of all these names.  In the web service there is a function defined returns the email address of the person, given their name.  We recently migrated our email from LotusNotes to outlook so we need this routine to return the email addresses in standard smtp format (jdoe@domain.com)  instead of canonical format.  The current code is below:

public String getSalespersonCommonName(String salesperson) throws Exception {

```
    try 
    {
        View salespersonView;
        DocumentCollection docs;

        d = s.getCurrentDatabase();

        if (d != null) {
            // get the salesperson
            salespersonView = d.getView("vAllSalespersons");

            docs = salespersonView.getAllDocumentsByKey(salesperson);

            if (docs.getCount() > 0)
            {
                doc = docs.getFirstDocument();

                return doc.getItemValueString("Salesperson");

            } else {
                return "";
            }

        } else {
            return "";
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to look up the user by name in the Domino Directory and get the SMTP address from there. The [Directory.LookupNames()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_LOOKUPNAMES_METHOD_DIRECTORY.html) method is the "official" way to do this since it works automatically with multiple directories, but I've seen lots of implementations that directly access a view in names.nsf.

But first, you will have to make sure that the user's Outlook SMTP address has actually been entered into the Domino Directory, and you will have to know which field it has been entered into. If the Outlook SMTP address is different from their old Domino SMTP address, it's fairly common practice to enter the Outlook address in the forwarding address field.

Comment: Good advice, but one minor clarification:  The documentation for the Java version of `lookupNames()` is at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_LOOKUPNAMES_METHOD_DIRECTORY_JAVA.html